# Related list for Indirect Lookup Relationship is not showing records

Tags: lookup, relationships, related-list

The child record looks up to its parent via an Indirect Lookup Relationship through an external Id field. I have written code that inserts the child against the parent. The child record is getting created and the lookup is also filled in properly; if I go to the child record detail page I can click on the parent lookup and navigate to the parent record.

The problem here is, when I go to the parent record detail page I am not seeing the child record. Even if the child record is created manually from the parent related list it doesn't show up (but the record gets created).

I am not sure what the missing link is.

**Indirect Lookup Detail**
[image]

**Newly Created Child Record**
[image]

**Parent Record**
[image]

Comment: Did you add the related list to the parent?

Comment: @Eric I checked the related list, the relationship, the layout, everything multiple times. Everything is there! Even creating the child manually produces the same outcome!

Comment: Did you check in ur code if you're performing DML Operation(Insert)?
Also did u add any specific condition in ur code for creating child record?

Comment: @DhananjayPatil I have even tried adding the child manually. See attached images.